# Сохранение файла из $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Все доброго дня!

В форме есть `input` типа file, который должен сохранять картинки на сервере, передаю картинки AJAX'ом в php функцию. Они передаются, но вот как их сохранить из массива $_FILES?

AJAX

```js
    function setimage() {
    var fd = new FormData(); 
    var input = document.getElementById("educ-doc-copy").files;        
    fd.append('educ', input[0]);

    input = document.getElementById("id-doc-copy").files;
    fd.append('id', input[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-content/themes/II/php/photores.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    });
    }
```

PHP

```php
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";
    $now = date('Y-m-d_h-i-sa');
    $file = $now .'.png';
    //file_put_contents($file,$_FILES['id']['tmp_name']);
    copy ( $_FILES['id'], $file );
?>
```

Вывод функций:

```html
    <div id="results"><pre>Array
    (
    )
    Array
    (
    [educ] =&gt; Array
        (
            [name] =&gt; Карта Тещи.jpg
            [type] =&gt; image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] =&gt; /tmp/php6Y0gs8
            [error] =&gt; 0
            [size] =&gt; 458882
        )

    [id] =&gt; Array
        (
            [name] =&gt; Без разгона.png
            [type] =&gt; image/png
            [tmp_name] =&gt; /tmp/phpt4FARP
            [error] =&gt; 0
            [size] =&gt; 1247953
        )

    )
    </pre></div>
```

Как мне это из этого массива файл сохранить?

Comment: http://g.zeos.in/?q=php%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5

Comment: По твоему я этого не делал, @Arch ?

Comment: Судя по вашему коду - __не делали__

Comment: Тебя должен интересовать ключ [tmp_name]  - это туда файл попадает в любом случаи, проходит всевозможные проверки и перекладывается или оставляется как ненужный

Answer (score 1):

```
<? 
// ....... Всякие проверки 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['educ']['tmp_name'], 'Путь куда нужно положить файл'); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['id']['tmp_name'], 'Путь куда нужно положить файл'); 
?>

<?
// Если загрузка не ожидаемая 
// Разумеется мы понимаем о проверке итд.
foreach($_FILES as $idd => $value){
   // $idd - это твои 'educ', 'id' и всё что ещё придумал
   if(isset($_FILES[$idd]['tmp_name']) and !empty($_FILES[$idd]['tmp_name'])){
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$idd]['tmp_name'], 'Путь куда нужно положить файл');
   };
};
?>
```